# Creating Runnables dynamically

Tags: android, animation

Please help
I have 3 ImageViews and I can move that 3 views with TranslateAnimation by using 3 Runnables.
Here is my code:

```
private Runnable run1= new Runnable() {   
    public void run() {
        if(t1)
        {
            LayoutParams params1=(LayoutParams) l1.getLayoutParams();
            params1.x=x1;
            params1.y=y1;
            l1.setLayoutParams(params1);
            x2=r.nextInt(720-80)+80;
            y2=r.nextInt(400-80)+80;

        TranslateAnimation ta1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, x2-x1, 0, y2-y1 );
        ta1.setDuration(800);
        ta1.setFillAfter(true);
        l1.startAnimation(ta1);
        x1=x2;
        y1=y2;

        handler.postDelayed(run1, 800);

        }
    }
```

};
then I have Run2, run3 like this, and run them by calling

```
    this.runOnUiThread(run1);
    this.runOnUiThread(run2);
    this.runOnUiThread(run3);
```

in OnCreate

Then I have Array with int c ImageViews(eg c=10, then c=20...)

```
for(j=0;j<c;j++)    
    { 

        mp[j] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), soundArray[i[j]]); 
        images[j]=new ImageView(getBaseContext());
        lp[j]=new LayoutParams(50,50, x1[j], y1[j]);
        images[j].setLayoutParams(lp[j]);
        images[j].setBackgroundResource(imgArray[i[j]]);
        images[j].setId(j);
        images[j].setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);
        abs.addView(images[j]);
    }
```

How can I do something like this with it?

How to create many Runnables dynamically?

This code not working

```
for(j=0;j<c;j++)    
    {
        run[j]=new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                if(t[j])

                {

                    params[j]=(LayoutParams) images[j].getLayoutParams();
                    params[j].x=x1[j];
                    params[j].y=y1[j];
                    images[j].setLayoutParams(params[j]);

                    x2[j]=r.nextInt(720-80)+80;
                    y2[j]=r.nextInt(400-80)+80;

                    ta[j] = new TranslateAnimation(0, x2[j]-x1[j], 0, y2[j]-y1[j] );
                    ta[j].setDuration(200);
                    ta[j].setFillAfter(true);
                    images[j].startAnimation(ta[j]);
                    x1[j]=x2[j];
                    y1[j]=y2[j];

                    handler.postDelayed(run[j], 200);   
                }
            }

      };
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)    
    {
        this.runOnUiThread(run[j]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create separate class. This class should implement Runnable.

```
public class Single implements Runnable{
    public ImageView img=new ImageView(getBaseContext());
    public boolean t=true;
    public int x2=0;
    public int y2=0;

    public void run() {
        if(t)

        {
            LayoutParams params=(LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
            params.x=x2;
            params.y=y2;
            img.setLayoutParams(params);

            x2=r.nextInt(randX);
            y2=r.nextInt(randY);

            TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, x2-params.x, 0, y2-params.y );
            ta.setDuration(1000);
            ta.setFillAfter(true);
            img.startAnimation(ta);

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);    
        }
    }

}
```

Then I can dynamically create array of objects of this class and for each object run animation.

```
public Single[] images;
images=new Single[c];

    for(j=0;j<c;j++)    
    {
        images[j]=new Single();
        images[j].x2=r.nextInt(randX);
        images[j].y2=r.nextInt(randY);
        images[j].t=true;
    }
    for(int j1=0;j1<c;j1++) 
    {

        this.runOnUiThread(images[j1]);
    }
```